# ASP.NET 2.0 project - dynamically generated control based on type?

Tags: asp.net, controls

Working on a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 project.

Anyone know of a free dynamic control that will render itself based upon the type it's assigned to?

For example, if I pass it a DateTime property, it should render as a date time picker. If I give it a string... a simple text box. Give it a list, and it will create a dropdown or listbox...

There has to be something out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't image there would be something out there that can just do everything.

You could definitely wrap a lot of controls into one control that you could generically type

```
public class ControlLoader<T> : System.Web.UI.Control where T : Type 
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            Controls.Add(/* some datetime picker you found */);
        }
        else if (...)
        { 
            //
        }            
        base.Render(writer);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I think this is where I tell you to build this yourself... it really wouldn't be too hard. You could use existing ASP.NET Controls and just load and render them dynamically based on the Type of the data passed in.

Comment: i think he's saying to build it yourself using something like if(typeof(var) == Date) etc.

Comment: see my updated answer for something that should get you started.

Comment: Boo ya. that's frickin sweet. I'm going to make this and bank a million. jk.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Great stuff.

Comment: awesome, if this is what you're looking for mark it as the answer, please