# Generating asp.net web controls based on properties types

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, properties

I have to generate asp.net webcontrols based on the property type (dateTime,String,List). 
Right now, i am using reflection to get property type and then inside a switch case i am creating a control. Example below

```
public DateTime date {get; set;}-->generate a datetime picker

public String Name {get; set;}-->generate a textbox control
```

I need to know if there any library or reusable class available for this requirement and also i need to know if my apporach is correct.

Comment: What means `based on the propery type`? You have two properties in this class, so how to check which is the one to choose?

Comment: Typo "Property Type"... If the property is of type DateTime then i need to generate a DateTime picker. String I should generate a textbox

Comment: So you have a method that takes an `object` and you check what type it is. According to that you want to generate a control? Why don't you use a generic method? `public static T GenerateControl<T>(object value)where T: WebControl`

Comment: Exactly this is my requirement...I just went through this post...I think i should do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158523/asp-net-2-0-project-dynamically-generated-control-based-on-type?rq=1

Comment: @Chandan Probably not related to your specific usecase, but have you looked at one of the naked objects frameworks?

Comment: My development platform is asp.net 2.0. I am not sure if naked objects helps me.